# Control tracked version of external dependency

Tags: version-control, dvc

I am trying to set up a DVC repository for machine learning data with different tagged versions of the dataset. I do this with something like:

```sh
$ cd /raid/ml_data  # folder on a data drive
$ git init
$ dvc init
$ [add data]
$ [commit to dvc, git]
$ git tag -a 1.0.0
$ [add or change data]
$ [commit to dvc, git]
$ git tag -a 1.1.0
```

I have multiple projects that each need to reference some version of this dataset. The problem is I can't figure out how to set up those projects to reference a specific version. I'm able to track the `HEAD` of the repo with something like:

```sh
$ cd ~/my_proj  # different drive than the remote
$ mkdir data
$ git init
$ dvc init
$ dvc remote add -d local /raid/ml_data  # add the remote on my data drive
$ dvc cache dir /raid/ml_data/.dvc/cache  # tell DVC to use the remote cache
$ dvc checkout
$ dvc run --external -d /raid/ml_data -o data/ cp -r /raid/ml_data data
```

This gets me the latest version of the dataset, symlinked into my `data` folder, but what if I want some projects to use the `1.0.0` version and some to use the `1.1.0` version, or another version? Or for that matter, if I update the dataset to `2.0.0` but don't want my existing projects to necessarily track `HEAD` and instead keep the version with which they were set up?

It's important to me to not create a ton of local copies of my dataset as the `/home` drive is much smaller than the `/raid` drive and some of these datasets are huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [data access](https://dvc.org/doc/start/data-access) set of commands.

In your particular case, `dvc import` makes sense:

```
$ dvc import /raid/ml_data data
```

if you want to get the most recent version (HEAD). Then you will be able to update it with the `dvc update` command (if 2.0.0 is released, for example).

```
$ dvc import /raid/ml_data data --rev 1.0.0
```

if you'd like to "fix" it to the specific version.

#### Avoiding copies

Make sure also, that `symlinks` are set for the second project, as described in the [Large Dataset Optimization](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/large-dataset-optimization):

```
$ dvc config cache.type reflink,hardlink,symlink,copy
```

(there are config modifiers `--global`, `--local`, `--system` to set this setting for everyone at once, or just for one project, etc)

Check the details instruction [here](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/large-dataset-optimization#configuring-dvc-cache-file-link-type).

---

Overall, it's a great setup, and looks like you got pretty much everything right. Please, don't hesitate to follow up and/or create other questions here- we'll help you with this.

Comment: That's great, thank you. How do I make sure that it uses symlinks for the project in the home directory? It seems like if I just use your first command I create a local copy that's linked to the "remote" on the raid drives.

Comment: @Engineero please take a look, I put some additional info and some links the to the relevant docs.